# Data set generation

Tags: data-analysis, data-mining

For my research work, I need to generate data set by using some standard statistical distribution. I have seen Unknown distribution for data set generation. I do not have any idea about unknown distribution and how to generate data using this distribution. Could you please clarify what is unknown distribution? My problem belongs to NP class, to test my algorithm, I need to generate data set using different statistical distribution.

Comment: You mean Uniform distribution?

Comment: No, uniform distribution has some pattern. I want to know that in some textbook I have seen that author used the term "These data are from some unknown distribution". I wondered if the distribution were unknown then how could they generate it.

Comment: There's something called an Empirical distribution which is the distribution of the data. Could this possibly be it? If it is from an unknown distribution then there is no way the data is generated except maybe from an empirical distribution of some other data

Comment: @Malcolm thank you for your advice. I will check it.